# forcing application to go straight to the server fetch the data and not on (cache from disk)

Tags: php, angular, google-chrome

I am developing an api and I was having problems retrieving my data in the chrome browser. even when they were changed and I tried to get a get all it would return the results before the change, this because when I tried to make a request of type get it instead of going straight to the server ia in the browser cache.

In my network Headers Status code became Status Code: 200 OK (cache from disk)

In other words, the values were incorrect because instead of going to the server it retrieved the cache. I was able to resolve this problem by disabling the browser cache. This is easy to solve since I am in development mode.

How do I do this in production mode? how do I get my application to go to the server and not to my cache from disk.

I am using angular 6 and php 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should set the header of api request cache-control to no-cache..........

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
```

Comment: I have a json class that is responsible for sending the client, should I set this json in this class or at the beginning of api?

Comment: ohk.......search where the header part is set in this class and if possible override Cache-Control value for particular api.

Comment: have you tried adding ?100001 or some random value in your request url. ex. http://www.yourweb.com/api/method/param?10001

Comment: No, why add the 100001 value?

Comment: My post / put / delete requests work perfectly the only problem is in get requests

Comment: by adding any random value browser detect it as new request So it won't served via cache.

Comment: When I try to perform a get on a new url it works, but after that this data goes to cache as well

Comment: to solve this you can generate any random number before request and add it request

Comment: logically this would work, but it would not be a correct approach

Comment: header("Content-Type: application/json");
header("Expires: on, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache"); try adding these header could work too.

Comment: Thank you, I had tested an approach almost the same one that you sent and it worked

Comment: Happy Coding Buddy :)